# Convert array of object to CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to generate a CSV to import some records into a Postgres DB and I get some issue with \".

I have the following object

```
obj = {
  "id"=>1,
  "event_id"=>2,
  "user_id"=>3,
  "items"=>[{:type => "laptop"}]
}
```

With the following code:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.generate_line([obj['id'],obj['event_id']obj['user_id']obj['items']])
```

I end up with the following line which break when trying to import into postgres due to the \"\" before and after 'laptop'.

```
1,2,3,\"{:type=>\"\"laptop\"\"}\"\n
```

Comment: What do you want that header for "items" to look like? This is because `to_s` is being called on that object.

Comment: I am curious as to why this is being stored as CSV anyway. Postgres supports JSON storage, and your structure appears to be better represented as JSON.

Comment: What format are the records in before you start? Why not skip the CSV and put them directly into the database?

Comment: I followed Brennan suggestion and used JSON. Works like a treat!